# If two plane lattices scale to contain each other, then are they equal?

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices

*Definition.* A lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ is a subgroup $L$ of $\mathbb{C}$ of the following form: for some $\omega_{1},\omega_{2}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ with $\omega_{1}/\omega_{2}\not\in\mathbb{R},$ 
$$L=\{n_{1}\omega_{1}+n_{2}\omega_{2}:n_{1},n_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$
If $\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$ and $L$ is a lattice as above, then we define
$$\gamma L = \{\gamma\omega:\omega\in L\}.$$

**Question.** Let $L$ and $M$ be lattices in $\mathbb{C}.$ Suppose $\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb{C}$ are non-zero and such that $\gamma L\subseteq M$ and $\delta M\subseteq L.$ Does it then follow that $\gamma L=M?$

---

**Context.**
I am working through Rick Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*. In Chapter III he considers holomorphic maps between complex tori, and appears to implicitly assume that the queried implication holds, but I can't see why it should be true.

---

**My thoughts so far.**
I could try contradiction. For example, if $\gamma L\subset M,$ then $\gamma\delta L\subset L,$ and I think it follows that $\lvert\gamma\delta\rvert>1,$ but I don't see where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $L=\Bbb Z+\Bbb Z i$, $M=\Bbb Z+\Bbb Z(2i)$,
$\gamma=2$ and $\delta=1$?

Comment: Hmm, yes... it does seem that the trivial cases are useful! I'm sure I must have simply missed something else in Miranda's proof.